# Azure SQL database first connection timeout and ADF

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I'm connecting to an Azure SQL database serverless instance as a source in Azure Data Factory.

I'm experiencing an issue where the first connection to the database times out as the database is suspended.

How is this typically handled in ADF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 : Increasing the connection timeout to 10minutes or more should solve it.

"connectionString": "Data Source=tcp:.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=;**Connection Timeout=600**"

The latency to auto-resume and auto-pause a serverless database is generally order of 1 minute to auto-resume and **1-10** minutes after the expiration of the delay period to auto-pause. - [Reference 1] :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview?view=azuresql#latency

Storing Connection Strings in Key-Vaults:
[2]:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault

Connection String- Reference
[3]:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-content-reference-guide?view=azuresql

Solution 2: is to setup the retry on the activities with a higher retry Interval.

Comment: The retry property on the activities!!! Perfect, Thanks! Why do i always look for a complicated solution?